# No bash, qual a diferença entre uma string nula e uma string vazia?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Gostaria de saber se existe diferença em como o bash representa as variáveis com valores nulos

```
var=
```

e com strings vazias

```
var=""
```

Quais cuidados devo ter ao manipular variáveis como essas?

Answer (score 3):

Considere o seguinte:

```
var1=

var2=""
```

A variável `var1` não tem valor algum, tem seu valor nulo (`null`). Um valor nulo é exatamente um "NADA"! Diferente do valor da variável `var2` que tem uma string em branco.

Imagine que estaremos usando alguma linguagem de objetos (só para ficar mais didático). Usando o exemplo com Python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 14:05:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> var1 = None
>>> var2 = ""
>>> type(var1)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> type(var2)
<type 'str'>
```

ps: `None` em [python](https://docs.python.org/2/) é a mesma coisa que `null` em outras linguagens.

A situação da `var1` demonstra que a variável não há inicialização de um valor. Logo, um "nada" não poderá receber algum retorno, caso tente... irá receber o famoso erro `NullPointerException` porque o "nada" não pode receber atributo(s): não recebe valores e aponta para nada.

```
>>> len(var1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

A `var2` é uma variável do tipo `string` vazia. Algo "vazio" tem seu valor de zero porque deste jeito a variável está inicializado. Ou seja, mesmo sendo um "caractere em branco" ele tem seu lugar reservado na memória. Então, quando utilizado o `len()` (length) será retornado `0`:

```
>>> len(var2)
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Por favor, considere o *shell script* em `sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh 

aNullString=
anEmptyString=""

if [ -z ${aNullString} ] ; then
    echo The string aNullString is empty 
else
    echo The string aNullString is not empty 
fi

if [ -z ${anEmptyString} ] ; then
    echo The string anEmptyString is empty 
else
    echo The string anEmptyString is not empty 
fi

if [ ${aNullString} = ${anEmptyString}] ; then
    echo The strings aNullString and anEmptyString are equal
else
    echo The strings aNullString and anEmptyString differ 
fi
```

Ele sugere que `a=` e `b=''` são a mesma cadeia de caracteres, pois seu resultado é:

```
The string aNullString is empty
The string anEmptyString is empty
The strings aNullString and anEmptyString are equal
```